# function to update iframe not called when called inside another onclick() function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function upLog() in a library.js file that updates an inframe in the document:

```
function upLog(sentence)
{
  $('#log-div').prepend('<p class="log-text">' + sentence + "</p>");
}
```

I have another scripts.js folder where when I call this function, it executes perfectly fine:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  upLog("bar");
});
```

However, there's a function called Buy() in library.js where I call the function and it doesn't work:

```
function Buy(choice_number)
{
  upLog('foo'); //this doesnt work
}
```

The inframe and the main document both are linked to scripts and library.js files. Buy() is executed on an onclick function:

```
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-block btn-warning" id="choice2" onclick="Buy(choice2);">
```

All other functions of Buy() are performed perfectly well, and I don't get an error in the console. Why is this happening?

Edit: I tried to remove the onclick() events and in the scripts.js file I added the following lines:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{

  $("#choice1").click(Buy(choice1));
  $("#choice2").click(Buy(choice2));
  $("#choice3").click(Buy(choice3));
});
```

But now, Buy() is being executed automatically on page load and I have no idea why.

Comment: do you mean "iframe" instead of "inframe"?

Comment: After your edit: Buy is executed because you put it inside the document ready event

Comment: Can you provide a minimal gist/codepen so we can debug it?

Comment: @Purefan Doesn't the function bound to the element by .click() only be executed when the element is clicked?

Comment: Duuh! yeah I misread that, sorry